# Retrieving data from adjacency list model database.(MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
function get_hierarchy_page()
{
    $detail = $this->input->post('name');
    $tree = $this->dashboard_model->get_detail($detail);
    $this->load->view('layout/layout', $data);

    if(isset($tree))
    {
        $data['hierarchy'] = $this->data_array_for_teacher($tree);
    }
}

function data_array_for_teacher($tree)
{
    if(!(isset($tree)))
        return 0;

    $data_query = mysql_query("select * from tbl_level");

    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_query))
    {
        $id = $result['level_id'];
        $data_array[$id] = $result;
    }

    //array to get level id
    while($level_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($tree))
    {
        $level_array[] = $level_result['level_id'];
    }

    if(!(isset($level_array)))
        return 0;

    foreach($level_array as $level)
    {
        $p   = $this->recursive_for_teacher($data_array,$level);    
        print_r($p);
    }
}

function recursive_for_teacher($data_array,$level_once)
{
    if(!isset($data_array,$level_once))
        return 0;

    $i = 0;
    static $p = array();
    $data = $data_array;
    $y = $level_once;
    $x = $data[$y]['level_parent'];
    $z = $data[$y]['level_name'];
    $y=$x;
    array_push($p,$z);
    $p[] = $z;

    if($y!=0)
        $this->recursive_for_teacher($data,$y);

    return $p;
}
```

I am working on a system which is based on hierarchical data stored in mysql using adjacency list model. I have 2 tables `tbl_user` and `tbl_level`. 
`tbl_level` has the following fields -`level_id`,`level_parent`,`level_name`. These three fields are the same as `id`,`parent_name`,`parent_id` respectively in a standard database structure.

In the table `tbl_level` there are many organizations and each one has different hierarchical structures.
I wrote the above code which solves my problem of getting the the whole hierarchy of any authority in  a given organization.
The only problem which i am now facing is when i am  getting the required answer in one array.
I need one array for each authority.
`Array(`
    
`[0] => Engineering and Technology`
    `[1] => Univ1`
    `[2] => Class`
    `[3] => Master of Business Administration`
    `[4] => Engineering and Technology`
    `[5] => univ1`
    `[6] => Class_cse`
    `[7] => Computer Science`
    `[8] => Bachelor of Technology`
    `[9] => Engineering and Technology`
    `[10] => univ1`
`)`

Can anyone suggest a better solution for the problem ?

Comment: `<div id="showlist<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>`  
`<script>show(<?php echo $row['level_id']; ?>,<?php echo $i; ?>)`   `</script>`. This is the 3rd day and i found the solution to my own problem successfully by using ajax to fetch each level individually.

Answer (score 1):

```
function parent_sort($categories)
{    
    foreach($categories as $item)
        $childs[$item->parent_id][] = $item;
    foreach($categories as $item) 
        if (isset($childs[$item->category_id]))
            $item->childs = $childs[$item->category_id];

    return $childs[0];
}
```

You can use this function to sort leveled array, and it will output sorted array by levels